# how to save the state of a page after F5

Tags: php, javascript

How can I save the state of a page after to press F5.(with php or javascript)

I have this page, which if I I press the button 1, div 1 disappears, and if you press the div 1 again, it reappears.
the button 2 has the same function.
is there any way that if I press button 1(or button2) disappears the div, and then if I press F5 continue the div1(or div2) hidden, ??

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" value="ID1"><br/>

    <div id="div1" name="div1"/> 
    <b>Hello1</b><br>
    <img src="pic1.png" height="100px" width="100px" /> 
    </div>
<input type="submit" id="button2" name="button2" value="ID2"><br/>

    <div id="div2" name="div2"/> 
    <b>Hello2</b><br>
    <img src="pic2.png" height="100px" width="100px" /> 
    </div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button1").toggle(function(){
            $("#div1").hide();
        }, 
        function(){
            $("#div1").show();
        });
    });
    //
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button2").toggle(function(){
            $("#div2").hide();
        }, 
        function(){
            $("#div2").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes there is, they're called client-side cookies. (or if you're fancy, html5 storage)

Comment: You can wrap all your JavaScript in the document ready function (you don't need two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Storage

When you want to save localy great amount of data, you have another opportunity — to use local storage (since HTML5). You can do it directly using JavaScript or using one of available jQuery plugins.

for example, with totalStorage:

```
 var scores = new Array();
scores.push({'name':'A', points:10});
scores.push({'name':'B', points:20});
scores.push({'name':'C', points:0});
$.totalStorage('scores', scores);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well Cookies could do the trick of saving the last state and so on.
If you aren't sure that html5 is available on all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

one way is to use HTML5 history for this.

```
var state = { div1: true, div2: false };
history.pushState(state, 'Page', 'mypage/10');
```

Comment: Please mention cross browser compatibility, this solution will not work on many older browsers.